# MockwebServer doesn't mock http call

Tags: java, okhttp, mockwebserver

I recently discovered MockWebServer library and I try to use it in my project with Junit and mockito.

I have this test method:

```
       @Test
       public void testGetUsers() throws Exception {
            MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
            server.start();
            MockResponse mockedResponse = new MockResponse();
            mockedResponse.setResponseCode(200);
            mockedResponse.setBody("{}");
            server.enqueue(mockedResponse);
            server.url("https://my-domain/user/api/users");
            JSONObject result = UserService.getUsers();
            assertNotNull(result);
            server.shutdown();
       }
```

My method getUsers() do the Http call :

```
public JSONObject getUsers() {
     String urlUser = "https://my-domain/user/api/users";
     Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlUser)
                .build();

     Response response = 
     MyConf.getOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
     .... //process users and return a json Object
}
```

And here is my gradle configuration:

```
compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2')
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.12.0'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.1.0'
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.8.4'
testCompile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'mockwebserver', version: '3.12.0'
```

When I launch the unit test, the http call is not mocked by Mockwebserver. I get a response from my real server and not the mocked response ("{}").

Can you help me with that ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it doesn't work as you expect it. In the git readme they give the following code example:

```
  // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
  HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/chat/");
```

So you're getting a URL by the mock server you'll have to call, not an overwrite of any existing URL.

I just double checked this with the following source code:

```
MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
server.start();
HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/chat/");
```

This gives for `baseUrl` a new address: http://127.0.0.1:8125/v1/chat/

Comment: My guess would be this line is the offending line:

`MyConf.getOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();` 

Inside `getUsers()` method, the OP isn't injecting a server, so the code is constructing a real one rather than using a mock that has been passed in?

Comment: That's correct, Thomas. He has to use the return value of server.url to determine which server should be called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand better now.
But, is there a way to use that baseURL without given it to getUsers() in parameter. I can't change getUsers()'s signature !

Comment: You can add a config class holding a public & static String with the baseURL and then overwrite it in your tests.